# Подскажите как выравнять элементы

Tags: css, веб-программирование, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap

```html
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Заголовок</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    
</head>

<div class="container">

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm title">
     <h1>Лучшие бизнес-идеи</h1>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
     <img src="http://uutvdome.ru/statii/da/1/121/liv68.jpg" alt=""
     class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm">
     <div class="justify-self-start">
      <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/8/3/4/2239438.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid"> 
     </div>

     <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/8/3/4/2239438.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
   </div>
  
  </div>
```

Подскажите как два правых изображения выровнять одно по верхней границе, а второе по нижней?

Comment: Спасибо  @puvvl !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой сбособ добавить классы `d-flex flex-column-reverse justify-content-between`. Перечень о работе `bootstrap` и `flex` [тут](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Заголовок</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm title">
      <h1>Лучшие бизнес-идеи</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <img src="http://uutvdome.ru/statii/da/1/121/liv68.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm d-flex flex-column-reverse justify-content-between">
      <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/8/3/4/2239438.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">

      <img src="http://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/8/3/4/2239438.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```